# Mongoose - Cannot call method 'findOne'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to add Facebook login using passport and i'm stuck at the following error:

**TypeError: Cannot call method 'findOne' of undefined at Strategy._verify**

I have required **models.js** in my app.js file and i'm passing into the passport model

**app.js**

```
var Models = require('./config/models');
require('./config/passport')(passport,loginStrategies,Models);
```

My passport model - **passport.js**:

```
module.exports = function(passport, loginStrategies, Models){
   //Passport serialize and deserialize user

   passport.use(new loginStrategies.FacebookStrategy({
      //FB App Config
    },function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {

    Models.User.findOne({uid: profile.id}, function(err, user) {
      if(user) {
        done(null, user);
      } else {
        var user = new Models.User();

        user.uid = profile.id;
        user.name = profile.displayName;
        user.email = profile.email;

        user.save(function(err) {
          if(err) {
            throw err;
          }
          done(null, user);
        });
      }
    });

    // ...
```

**Models.js**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
module.exports = function(){

    DB_URL = "mongodb://localhost/test";

    //User Schema

    var UserSchema = new Schema({
        uid: Number,
        name: String,
        email: String,
    });


    mongoose.connect(DB_URL);

    mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

    return{
        User : mongoose.model('User')   
    }; 

};
```

Comment: How is `Models` being defined? `models.js` is exporting a `function` that will need to be called in other modules that `require` it.

Comment: I have modified the post to include the app.js file. I'm requiring it there and then passing it into the passport.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `models.js` is exporting a `function`:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
module.exports = function(){ // <!---
    // ...
};
```

A call of it will need to be included for the `Object` with the `User` model to be `return`ed. Either where the module is `require`d:

```
var Models = require('./config/models')();
//                                     ^^
require('./config/passport')(passport,loginStrategies,Models);

console.log(typeof Models);    // 'object'
console.log('User' in Models); // true
```

Or, where it's being used:

```
module.exports = function(passport, loginStrategies, Models){
   //Passport serialize and deserialize user

   var models = Models();

   // ...

       models.User.findOne(...);
```